# ERROR:this.scrollableDiv.nativeElement is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to call `scrollIntoView` on a **HTML** element in a component. But I got error like bellow.

> ERROR TypeError: "_this.scrollableDiv.nativeElement is undefined"

**Component Code**

```
  @Input("data") detailData : any = {};
  @ViewChild('scrollableDiv') scrollableDiv: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.detailData);
   const myNode = this.detailData;
   console.log(myNode)

    if (myNode) {
      console.log(this.detailData);
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.scrollableDiv.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start" });
      });

     }

  }
```

In **HTML** I've provided like bellow

**HTML**

```
<div [id]="detailData.key" #scrollableDiv>
```

Hope anyone can help me, please...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share it in stackbiltz

Comment: it quite big... Okey..I try to make it simple..

Answer (score 2):

ngOnInit is called before the view children has the chance to register.

Use ngAfterViewInit() instead.

Comment: You are right, I didn't notice it was in `ngOnInit`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. But still got the same error `ERROR TypeError: "that.scrollableDiv.nativeElement is undefined"`

Comment: "that.scrollable" could it be that somewhere else you are using "that" instead of this ?